# How to call combine multiple completion handlers to combine data to one new array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been stuck for a while now and any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am creating an app that uses Firebase database and I have created 5 classes that hold different data in Firebase. I'm creating a tableview that needs to display information from each of the 5 classes (Profile name, image, then information about a league, and info about scores). So in my new class I created a function calling for data from firebase from each class... 
For example: GET all players from X league {
    FOR every player in the league {
        GET the players information 
        THEN GET the scores
        THEN on and on
        once we have all information APPEND to new array
}
     and then rank the array
}

After all this runs I want to reload the table view on the VC

SO my solution works on the original load but if I back out and re enter the screen the names and images repeat.

To be exact when the indexes print to the console I get 
"Player 1: Zack"
"Player 2: John"
However, the screen shows John's image and name repeatedly. BUT only that class... All other data stays where it is supposed to be. And the original functions are all written the same way.

I'm thinking it's something to do with memory management or I wrote my completion handler poorly?

Here is the code in the new array class:

You'll also notice that my completion() is inside my for in loop which I HATE but it's the only way I could get the function to finish before completing.. Otherwise the function completes before the data is ready.

```
func getLeaderboard(leagueID: String, completion: @escaping ()->()) {

        print("League Count After removeAll \(self.rankedGolfers.count)")
        self.leagueMembers.getLeagueMembers(leagueID: leagueID) {
            print("HANDLER: Step 1: Get League Members")

            for member in self.leagueMembers.leagueMembers {

                print("Golfer Member ID: \(member.userID)")
                self.golferInfo.getGolferInfo(userKey: member.userID, completion: {
                    print("HANDLER: Step 2: Get player profile info")
                    print("Golfer Name3: \(self.golferInfo.golfers[0].firstName) \(self.golferInfo.golfers[0].lastName)")
                    self.handicapHelper.getRounds(userID: member.userID, completion: {
                        print("HANDLER: Step 3: Get players Handicap")
                        print("Golfer Handicap3: \(self.golferInfo.golfers[0].lastName): \(self.handicapHelper.handicap)")

                        self.leagueInfo.getLeagueInfo(leagueID: leagueID, completion: {
                            print("HANDLER: Step 4: Get league info")
                            let golferIndex = self.golferInfo.golfers[0]
                            let memberInfoIndex = self.leagueInfo.leagueInfo[0]
                            let golferID = member.userID
                            let profileImg = golferIndex.profileImage
                            let golferName = "\(golferIndex.firstName) \(golferIndex.lastName)"
                            let handicap = self.handicapHelper.handicap
                            let golferLeaguePardieScore = member.pardieScore
                            let leagueRoundsPlayed = member.numberOfRounds
                            let roundsRemaining = memberInfoIndex.leagueMinRounds - leagueRoundsPlayed
                            let currentWinnings = member.currentWinnings

                            let newGolfer = Leaderboard(golferID: golferID, profileImg: profileImg ?? "No Img", golferName: golferName, golferHandicap: handicap, golferLeaguePardieScore: golferLeaguePardieScore, roundsPlayedInLeague: leagueRoundsPlayed, roundsRemaining: roundsRemaining, currentWinnings: currentWinnings)

                            self.rankedGolfers.append(newGolfer)

                            print("HANDLER: Step 5: Add golfer to array")
                            //print("Golfer Name 4: \(newGolfer.golferName)")
                            //print("Rounds Remaining: \(newGolfer.roundsRemaining)")
                            print("league Member Count: \(self.rankedGolfers.count)")
                            self.getLeaderboardRanking()
                            print("HANDLER: Step 6: Rank Array")
                            //print("COMPLETION: \(self.rankedGolfers.count)")
                            completion()
                        })
                    })

                })
            }
        }

}
```

Thank you for any help possible!

Comment: Why do you have 'completion()' inside the fast enumeration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can solve this with a DispatchGroup, which will ensure all of the data is loaded for each user, then append the user to an array used as a tableView dataSource and then reload the tableView upon completion.

To keep it simple we'll start with a UserInfo class which stores their uid, name, favorite food and handicap.

```
class UserInfoClass {
    var uid = ""
    var name = ""
    var favFood = ""
    var handicap = 0
}
```

and a class var array used as the dataSource for the tableView

```
var userInfoArray = [UserInfoClass]()
```

Then, assuming we have a structure like this...

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Leroy"

handicaps
   uid_0
      amt: 4

fav_foods
   uid_0
      fav_food: "Pizza"
```

...here's a function that reads all users, then iterates over each one populating a UserInfoClass with their name and uid, as well as creating a dispatch group that also populates their favorite food and handicap. When that's complete the user is added to the dataSource array and when all of the users are read the tableView is reloaded to display the information.

```
func loadUsersInfoAndHandicap() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("users")
    self.userInfoArray = []
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for user in allUsers {
            let uid = user.key
            let name = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"

            let aUser = UserInfoClass()
            aUser.uid = uid
            aUser.name = name

            group.enter()
            self.loadFavFood(withUid: uid) {favFood in
                aUser.favFood = favFood
                group.leave()
            }

            group.enter()
            self.loadHandicap(withUid: uid) { handicap in
                aUser.handicap = handicap
                group.leave()
            }

            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.userInfoArray.append(aUser)
            }
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("done, reload the tableview")
            for user in self.userInfoArray {
                print(user.uid, user.name, user.favFood, user.handicap)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

the users name and uid is read from the main users node and here are the two functions that read their favorite food and handicap.

```
func loadFavFood(withUid: String, completion: @escaping(String) -> Void) {
    let thisUser = self.ref.child("userInfo").child(withUid)
    thisUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let food = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fav_food").value as? String ?? "No Fav Food"
        completion(food)
    })
}

func loadHandicap(withUid: String, completion: @escaping(Int) -> Void) {
    let thisUser = self.ref.child("handicaps").child(withUid)
    thisUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let handicap = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "amt").value as? Int ?? 0
        completion(handicap)
    })
}
```

note that self.ref points to my firebase so substitute a reference to *your* firebase.

Note I typed this up very quickly and there is essentially no error checking so please add that accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thank you so much for your help..however I'm still getting the same issue.
When I load for the first time everything loads correctly.. Then if I back out and go back in the data repeats on person.. Here is the console.. How it's printing is how it's showing up on the table view.

Golfer Name: Zack Blauvelt
Golfer Handicap 13.1
Golfer Name: John Smith
Golfer Handicap 15.8
Golfer Name: John Smith
Golfer Handicap 15.8
Golfer Name: John Smith
Golfer Handicap 15.8

Comment: @ZackBlauvelt If you run the code above multiple times, It will load the tableView dataSource array with *copies* of the data. e.g if you have 5 users, run the code, the array will have 5 users. if you run it again without quitting the app, it will have 10 users. You can change that behavior by resetting the array when this code is called with a `self.userInfoArray = []`. It appears in the code right after the function name.